# how to add a date time type of data in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I am working on a school project which requires the user to input some data in the entry widgets in a Tkinter window which is stored in an excel file as a table
for ex:

| task | start time | finish time | complete % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task1 | 1/1/2022 | 1/3/2022 | 55 |

Task, start time, and finish time contain text and complete % contains numbers that are considered as string values.

I also know how to change start time and finish time to date type object using .date()

However, the problem is when I append start time and finish time as str in excel they are appended as a general type value and if I append them as date type object they are appended as a custom type value whereas the desired type is short date

So I wanted to know if it is possible that somehow Excel converts whatever I add under start and finish time as a short date or some method using openpyxl to append them as short date in the Excel file

Following is the code i have written:

```
def sub1():
global task_e, start_e, finish_e, comp_e
t=task_e.get()
s=start_e.get()
f=finish_e.get()
c=comp_e.get()

if(len(t)==0 or len(s)==0 or len(f)==0 or len(c)==0):
    mb.showwarning("Missing info","All of the fields are required to be filled")

else:
    workbook_name="gantt_charts14.xlsx"
    wb=load_workbook(workbook_name)
    page=wb.active
    records=[[t,s,f,c]]
    for info in records:
        page.append(info)
    wb.save(filename=workbook_name)
    mb.showinfo("Records added","Data succesfully added to excel sheets")
    task_e.delete(0, END), start_e.delete(0, END), finish_e.delete(0, END), comp_e.delete(0, END)
```

I am using openpyxl since I have to append similar data many times my problem

ps: I would prefer it if there is some method using openpyxl and not pandas as there is some other part of code that shows some error while using pandas

sample of what I'm getting [the above 2 rows are manually written by me after opening excel and the last row is how python appended the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcfM3.png)

Comment: Could you specify what values does task_e, start_e etc. take? It is not clear as to which date time format are you printing to your excel file.

Comment: Oh Im sorry i missed that I would just change that

Comment: Please add the Date time format, there is no way of knowing if you are using DDMMYY or MMDDYY etc. Also, do add sample output of expected output vs what you are observing.

Comment: the date-time format I'm expecting is MMDDYY

Comment: Just use date objects and the relevant number format.

Comment: that is not working since excel accepts that as a custom value instead of short date

Answer (score 0):

To print date in a particular format to a xlsx file you will have to used NamedStyle present in the Openpyxl module [(1)](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html). Inside NamedStyle you'll have to pass the format of date that you'd like to print in the xlsx file. Rest Openpyxl module itself shall take care of it when it prints. I have modified your script and taken dummy values for the sake of testing. The following should help you out to solve this problem.

```
import openpyxl
import datetime

def sub1():
    global task_e, start_e, finish_e, comp_e
    t="Task 2"
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
    end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-04", "%Y-%m-%d")
    c="35"

    if(len(t)==0 or len(s)==0 or len(f)==0 or len(c)==0):
        mb.showwarning("Missing info","All of the fields are required to be filled")

    else:
        workbook_name="gantt_charts14.xlsx"
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(workbook_name)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        page=wb.active
        records=[[t,start_time,end_time,c]]
        datestyle = openpyxl.styles.NamedStyle(name='DateStyle', number_format='MM/DD/YY')
        wb.add_named_style(datestyle)
    
    for i,info in enumerate(records):
        page.append(info)
        ws.cell(row=i+1,column=1).value = info[0]
        
        start_time_cell = ws.cell(row=i+1,column=2)
        start_time_cell.style = 'DateStyle'
        start_time_cell.value = info[1]

        finish_time_cell = ws.cell(row=i+1,column=3)
        finish_time_cell.style = 'DateStyle'
        finish_time_cell.value = info[2]

        ws.cell(row=i+1,column=4).value = info[3]
    
    wb.save(filename=workbook_name)

sub1()
```

Comment: You don't need NamedStyles to set a date format.

Comment: i tried using the method u showed however an error pops up saying that datestyle is not a known style

Comment: @hari The error is popping because of the conflict in the variable datestyle and the NameStyle name attribute. I have editted the answer do take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but I think your code is causing some more errors so should I create a new post or change my code in this question and show the error that I am facing after implementing your code?

Comment: @hari Please update the error in the same post and also share the complete code.